# Change a title of a new Entity in dynamics-crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In my create new entity page, i want modify the title text:

[image]

Do you have any idea how i can do it with Ribbon workbench or directly from XML?

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify that text, because it's automatically generated combining the word "New" and the name of the entity (both in the language of the user)

Comment: the problem is for masculine noun entities I want to have:

    Nouveau "NameOfEntity"

and for feminine noun entities I want to have:

    Nouvelle "NameOfEntity"

Comment: It's a common problem with other languages as well (as Italian), there isn't a supported way to change this behavior

Comment: It is possible to update the translation files to have a non-gender specific term? (if one exists!)